# TabLayout Mode scrollable doesn't fit well for tablets

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-tablayout

My tablayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

Here is the result on phone:
[image]

And on tablet:
[image]

[image]

You can see that I have 3 tabs: at, after and recurrence. On phones, tab width is not the same so that they can fit very well for `DialogFragment`. But on tablets, their widths become the same even these 3 words' length is very different.

My SDK version is Android 4.1(the phone) and 4.3(the tablet, I also test it on 4.4 and same problem). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this it may be help.I can show Tab like this way.

```
public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {
    public CustomTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        try {
            if (getTabCount() == 0)
                return;
            Field field = TabLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mTabMinWidth");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(this, (int) (getMeasuredWidth() / (float) getTabCount()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got your idea. Now I add `app:tabMinWidth="56dp"` for `TabLayout` in my `layout.xml` and it turns good. Thank you.

Comment: If It help you Then Mark it Accept Answer ?